# Css file not loading for others

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I recently created a [blog](http://www.apptec.net). The site looks fine when I open it(apart from a small problem that  it shows me `http://apptech.net.previewdns.com/` in the url instead of `http://www.apptec.net`.

### Problem

When someone else opens the site, it showsthe url `apptec.net` and the `.css` files are not loaded on the browser as a result he sees the site without the `css` files.

### What have I tried

I have tried to log out as the admin and then see the site but it shows the site with the `.css` files to me in both cases.

### My Request

I don't get what is wrong. I would be very thankful if anyone could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you may have the wrong path for your css file  Can you include your HTML where you call your CSS file?

Comment: Can you post the original bad code here, so that this question will be useful to others?

Comment: It was an error due to wrong url submission. The webhosting was bought on a different name and I was installing another domain on it. It had the url of the old domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Wordpress thinks it is installed at the previewdns domain. Log into your admin, go to settings (wp-admin/options-general.php) and check your WordPress address (URL) and Site address (URL) are correctly set to the main domain.

EDIT

It seems that you've done that now, and have a different problem - it looks like your chosen theme - 'Genesis' -  is not active on the live server. Again, you should be able to fix this in your Wordpress admin panel, in Appearance.

Comment: Thankyou. The wordpress address was written wrong. Once I put the right address everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your css link is incorrect.

Change it to a relative link and that should work fine. When I type in the address 
`http://apptech.net/wp-content/themes/genesis/style.css`
I get a page not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Your css files are going to a 404 page:
http://apptech.net/wp-content/themes/genesis/style.css

My theory is that your site is using a `<?php get_template_directory(); ?>` to set the path to your theme files.

Try changing your WordPress Address and Site URL under Settings to apptech.net

Alternately, you could go into your theme's header.php and find any `<?php get_template_directory(); ?>` and replace them with absolute paths to your css, images, and javascript.